# How to create facebook album and upload photos to the facebook album using android java?

Tags: java, android, facebook, photos

can anybody give me an example how to create album and upload photos to the facebook albums using java from android device?
I found a way how to upload photos one by one to the facebook wall, but not found way to create album and upload photos.

Thank you very much,

Comment: If an answer solved your question, you should accept it. Thats how SO works.

Answer (score 6):

Our developer blog has a [nice tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) on how to use the Graph API to upload photos.  Although the code is in PHP, you can translate the sample code easily for Java.  The relevant part of the tutorial is probably scenario 2: creating a new album and adding a photo.

To create a new album using our Graph API, you first need to have an access token that has the permission `publish_stream`.  Then to create the new album:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "My Test Album Name Here");
params.putString("message", "My Test Album Description Here");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/albums", params, "POST", new CreateAlbumListener());
```

And in your `CreateAlbumListener` class, grab the newly created album ID in the `onComplete()` method.  Once you have the album ID of the album you just created, to upload photos to that album:

1) Upload local photo (e.g. from gallery), assuming we have a variable `data` that is the byte array of the photo we wish to upload

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("photo", data);
params.putString("caption", "Test description here");
mAsyncRunner.request("ALBUM_ID/photos", params, "POST");
```

2) Upload from remote (e.g. a URL to a photo)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("url", "http://www.lolbrary.com/content/454/facebook-cat-9454.jpg");
params.putString("caption", "Cats are awesome");
mAsyncRunner.request("ALBUM_ID/photos", params, "POST");
```

`ALBUM_ID` is the variable that stores the album id of the album you just created.  You can checkout [HackBook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook), which is a sample app that we created to show you all the different calls you can do with the android SDK.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Jesse. You helped me a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: There is a little problem. Can you please tell how to get the created album_id from the response?

Comment: In your `CreateAlbumListener`, you have to implement the `onComplete` method. The `onComplete` method has a `String` variable called `response`, parse the `response` in the `onComplete` method to extract the album id.  Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi ... I am trying to write this function: mAsyncRunner.request("ALBUM_ID/photos", params, "POST"); , but it said:"The method request(String, Bundle, AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener) in the type AsyncFacebookRunner is not applicable for 
 the arguments (String, Bundle, String)"....Do you know if I should put any new listener class as the last parameter like I did with the album creation ?

Comment: @orikoko I think you might need a `null` at the end I might've forgotten to add that in the code

Comment: @JesseChen can you see this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677592/create-album-using-facebook-sdk-android/13677628#13677628